# Awk parsing of unique IP addresses from maillog

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Yesterday I asked a question here about a [oneliner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190275/oneliner-to-calculate-complete-size-of-all-messages-in-maillog) and [mjschultz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288349/mjschultz) gave me an answer that I instantly fell in love with :) Awk just destroyed the task at hand, parsing a large logfile (500+ MB) in a matter of seconds. Now I'm trying to port my other oneliners to awk.

This is the one in question:

```
grep "pop3\[" maillog | grep "User logged in" |  
egrep -o '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | sort -u
```

I need the list of all unique IP addresses using pop3 to connect to the mail server.

This is an example log entry:

```
Nov 15 00:49:21 hostname pop3[19418]: login: [10.10.10.10] username plaintext  
User logged in
```

So I find all the lines containing "pop3" and I parse them for the "User logged in" part. Next i use egrep and a regex to match IP addresses and I use sort to filter out the duplicate addresses.

This is what I have so far for my awk version:

```
awk '/pop3\[.*.User logged in/ {ip[$7]=0} END {for (address in ip)  
{ print address} }' maillog
```

This works perfectly but as always not all log entries are identical, for example sometimes the IP gets moved to the 8th field like here:

```
Nov 15 10:42:40 hostname pop3[2232]: login: hostname.domain.com [20.20.20.20]  
username plaintext User logged in
```

What would be the best way to catch those entries with awk as well?

As always thanks for all the great responses in advance, you've taught me so much already :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AWK code**

just match your ip format ... be careful that there are no other formats ...

```
/pop3\[.*.User logged in/    {
         where = match($0,/\[[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)
         if (where)
           ip[substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)]=0
} 

END {for (address in ip)  
{ print address} }
```

running at [ideone](http://ideone.com/clone/DlKkh)

Comment: Perfect! Just what I need, and thank you for ideone, never seen the site until now, that is going on my bookmarks toolbar ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

That looks more like Perl territory than Awk to me:

```
my %ip_addresses = ();
while (<>)
{
    next unless m/pop3\[/;
    next unless m/User logged in/;
    if (my($ip) = $_ =~ m/( \d{1,3} (?: [.] \d{1,3} ){3} )/msx)
    {
         $ip_addresses{$ip} = 1;
    }
}
foreach my $ip (sort keys %ip_addresses)
{
    print "$ip\n";
}
```

The sort is less than perfect - being alphabetic rather than numeric (so 192.1.168.10 will appear before 9.25.13.26).  That can be fixed, of course.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing and trying these approaches I got a new idea.

belisarius's code does what I asked for but since it has to do all the regex matching it's not the fastest one and speed is what I'm after.

So I came up with this, as you can see the "problematic" log lines have an extra field, making them all 13 fields long instead of the normal 12, so I just delete the extra field, this gives me the correct list of IP addresses, next i use awk again to delete all duplicate entries:

```
awk '/pop3\[.*.User logged in/ {{if (NF == 13) $7="";gsub(FS "+",FS)};print $7}'
/var/log/maillog | awk '!($0 in a){a[$0];print}'
```

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/yx35L) if you want to see the code in action